# get the column name during runtime with entityframework

Tags: string, entity-framework-5

I have a stored procedure that is run and returns a result set into a model (using EF 5).

As I'm looping through the result set, **I simply want to get the name of the column in the model that is used to hold the data.**

How can I achieve this?

Would it be something like below:

```
var myCustomers = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>
                                      ("exec SelectCustomers").ToList();

                    foreach (Customer cust in myCustomers)
                    {

                    }
```

Displaying the value "**myCustomers[0].Address1**" during runtime will display the **actual value** inside that field, **but how can I simply extract the column name**?

If I try something like below, the index value is **always** -1 and I don't know what I'm missing. I've used it dozens of times.

```
int Idx = myCustomers[0].Address1.IndexOf(".").ToString();
"-1"
```

Comment: I think I got it... I need to wrap it in a string as follows: "myCustomers[0].Address1".IndexOf(".").ToString();
"14". So, the idea now is to do a Substring("myCustomers[0].Address1", 14) where it will then give me the actual name of the filed "Address1". If there is more direct way via EF to get this done, I would appreciate it if anyone would let me know. Otherwise, I'll use this...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reliably do that. EF consists of 3 layers - object layer (also called O-Space - your types), conceptual layer (also called C-Space - a model in EDM terms) and store layer (also called S-Space which described the database). The mapping between O-Space and S-Space is more or less 1:1 - so a property on a class maps to an entity property in the OSpace model. However there are a few strategies of mapping C-Space to S-Space like Table Per Hierarchy (TPH), Table per Type (TPT), Table per Concrete type (TPC) and Entity Splitting (you can find more details here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/10/25/inheritance-mapping-a-walkthrough-guide-for-beginners.aspx). It is also possible to use your own name for a property that will be different from the name of a corresponding column in the database. In the simplest cases property names will match column names but oftentimes it won't be the case. At runtime the information about mapping is stored types that are mostly internal and you cannot access them. The information about mapping is populated from the Msl artifact the describes mapping between C- and S- space. You could try parsing this artifact (it's an Xml file) but it's not an easy task if you need to support all different mapping strategies.