# How do I find the table and column a property maps to in the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I get the information from `ObjectContext.Metadata` at runtime to find what column in what table a property on an object is mapped to?

EDIT:

I'm happy if this only works for entities that map to one and only one table.

Comment: Asked many times before, the closest to an answer I can find in a quick scan is this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13041422/861716

Comment: I haven't found an answer that actually answers the question. Some suggest loading XML but that doesn't always exist.

Comment: I don't think you can reliably tell this without parsing the edmx.

Comment: So if the context was made by Code First you are out of luck?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use MetaData, but here's how I do it :)

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public static string GetFullTableName(this Type t)
    {

        string exp = "[{0}].[{1}]";

        if (Attribute.IsDefined(t, typeof(TableAttribute)))
        {
            var attr = (TableAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).First();
            return string.Format(exp, attr.Schema, attr.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format("[dbo].[{0}]", t.Name);
        }
    }
```